# Select particular items if statement is fulfilled SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Does exist something like:

```
@isParamSet int
SELECT
CASE
WHEN @isParamSet=1 THEN Name, Surname
END
telNumber
FROM DETAILS
```

This is a stored procedure of course.

Comment: what should happen when `@isParamSet <> 1`

Comment: Is this MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: A SQL query returns a specific set of columns.  If you want a variable number of columns, then you either need multiple statements or dynamic SQL (which are the two answers given).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `SQL Server`:

```
IF @isParamSet = 1
  SELECT
    Name,
    Surname,
    telNumber
  FROM DETAILS
ELSE
  SELECT
    telNumber
  FROM DETAILS
```

You can also use Dynamic-SQL to build column list.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
      N'SELECT
        {other}
        telNumber
      FROM DETAILS';

SELECT @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '{other}', CASE
                                       WHEN @isParamSet = 1 THEN 'Name, Surname, '
                                       ELSE ''
                                       END );

EXEC [dbo].[sp_executesql]
     @sql;
```

**EDIT:**

You can pass arguments to Dynamic-SQL like

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
      N'SELECT
        {other}
        telNumber
      FROM DETAILS
      WHERE country = @country';

SELECT @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '{other}', CASE
                                       WHEN @isParamSet = 1 THEN 'Name, Surname, '
                                       ELSE ''
                                       END );

EXEC [dbo].[sp_executesql]
     @sql
     ,N'@country NVARCHAR(100)' -- pass correct type
     ,@country;
```

Comment: thanks! and What if I want to add WHERE clause? e.g. I've got another variable like... @country. Where do I put 
"WHERE 
country = @country"??

Comment: @Matt See updated answer. You can build your query as you want

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)

set @sql  = 'SELECT ' +
CASE
WHEN @isParamSet=1 THEN 'Name, Surname,' else ''
END + '
telNumber
FROM DETAILS'

Exec sp_executesql @sql
```